# Получить данные из input

Tags: php, html

Как средствами php вывести данные из формы, точнее из `input=text` есть запись, как ее оттуда вывести?

Answer (score 5):

```
<form method="post" action="Имя обработчика">
   <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Введите Ваше Имя" />
   <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

php - обработчик

```
<?php 
   $user = htmlspecialchars($_POST["user"]);
   ... и так далее ....................
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Есть несколько типов отправки данных: **POST** и **GET**
Советую об этом почитать:

- [Самоучитель PHP: Глава 4. Формы](http://www.php5.ru/study/forms)
- [Передача переменных через формы](http://ru.html.net/tutorials/php/lesson11.php)

Или хотя бы посмотреть:

- [Отправка данных get и post](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e2hhcMJfv8c)